# java webstart time

Tags: java, datetime, time, timezone, java-web-start

When running the JWS application after the update, the time zone is not set correctly, after restart application time zone is correctly set.

main method...

```
logger.info("TimeZone=" + TimeZone.getDefault());
logger.info("Date=" + new Date());
logger.info("Timestamp=" + new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
```

***First run(after upgrade):***

```
2012-10-15 16:51:49,529 [javawsApplicationMain]  INFO - TimeZone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
2012-10-15 16:51:49,531 [javawsApplicationMain]  INFO - Date=Mon Oct 15 16:51:49 UTC 2012
2012-10-15 16:51:49,531 [javawsApplicationMain]  INFO - Timestamp=2012-10-15 16:51:49.531
```

***Second run(from cache):***

```
2012-10-15 19:52:44,798 [javawsApplicationMain]  INFO - TimeZone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+03:00",offset=10800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
2012-10-15 19:52:44,798 [javawsApplicationMain]  INFO - Date=Mon Oct 15 19:52:44 GMT+03:00 2012
2012-10-15 19:52:44,798 [javawsApplicationMain]  INFO - Timestamp=2012-10-15 19:52:44.798
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you persist any time zone settings that get initialized from a config file or DB property?

Comment: no time zone is not set anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your application, `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone zone)` would be being called in between the first run and second run.

Please check the code base or add a breakpoint on above method and run your application in a debugger, you will find the location of call.